# refresh the comment list after form submitted

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am creating a CommentBox.

I am trying to refresh the comment list after form submission.

```
#CommentBox.js
const CommentBox = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="comment_area clearfix mb-5">
        <div className="section-heading style-2 mb-5">
            <h4>Comment</h4>
            <div className="line"></div>
        </div>
        < CommentForm />
        < CommentList />
    </div>
    
 );
}
```

As you can see I have different components for CommentForm.js and CommentList.js

```
#CommentForm.js
 const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
 ........
  axios.post(......................)
 ................................
  }
  return (
         <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
         |
         |
         </form>
 );

#CommentList.js
 useEffect(() => {
    const id = props.postId;
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        
        const res = await axios.get(
          `.......................`
        )
        setComments(res.data.results);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchData();
}, [props.postId])

return (
.................
.................
......
)
```

How should I write the GET Method  in form onsubmitHandler().
Or I have to change some other things to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve this is to move the state to your parent component, that is, make the axio calls to the parent component CommentBox. The CommentForm notifies the parent via callback that the form has been submitted and then you link one axios call after the other, passing the GET results to CommentList.

```
const CommentBox = (props) => {

const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
 ........
  axios.post(.......)
       .then(() => axios.get())
       .then((res) => setComments(res.data);
}

return (
    <div className="comment_area clearfix mb-5">
        <div className="section-heading style-2 mb-5">
            <h4>Comment</h4>
            <div className="line"></div>
        </div>
        < CommentForm onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}/>
        < CommentList comments={comments}/>
    </div>
 );
}
```